# Reading uploaded image: undefined method `file' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, rmagick

I receive the following error when I try to get image during thumbnail creation:

```
undefined method `file' for nil:NilClass
```

My code:

```
  version :thumb do
      img = ::Magick::Image::read(@file.file).first
      w = img.columns
      h = img.rows

      if w < h
        process :resize_to_limit => [30, 50]
      else
        process :resize_to_limit => [50, 30]
      end
  end
```

Any ideas what is this not working?

Comment: Your `@file` is nil.Can you post the code where the `@file` is initialized?

Comment: @Pavan, I was looking at this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413730/carrierwave-getting-image-width-and-height-and-storing-it-in-an-hstore-field. `@file` is initialized by Carrierwave, I think